# Addition Formula for Laguerre Polynomial

Tags: special-functions, orthogonal-polynomials

I am curious to know if some kind of addition formula can be derived for the following cases,

\begin{equation}
\exp{\left(x y \cos{\phi}\right)} L_n^\alpha\left(x^2 + y^2 - 2 x y \cos{\phi}\right)  
\end{equation} 
or 
\begin{equation}
\exp{\left(-x^2 + x y \cos{\phi}\right)} L_n^\alpha\left(x^2 + y^2 - 2 x y
\cos{\phi}\right) \left(x^2 - x y \cos{\phi}\right)^\gamma\,, \quad \gamma \ge 0
\end{equation}

I am aware of the Bateman's form, 
\begin{equation}
\exp{\left(x y e^{i \phi}\right)} L_n\left(x^2 + y^2 - 2 x y
\cos{\phi}\right)  = \sum_{k = 0}^\infty \left(x y e^{i\phi}\right)^{(k - n)}
\frac{n!}{k!} L_n^{(k - n)}\left(x^2\right) L_n^{(k - n)}\left(y^2\right) 
\end{equation}
The idea is to exponentiate the $\phi$ dependence to analytically perform the angular integration.

Answer (score -1):

I found the answer. The addition formula for associated Laguerre polynomial was derived by T. Koornwinder,  SIAM J. MATH. ANAL.
Vol. 8, No. 3, May 1977.